# How do i make discord.py send an error message into chat

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Ok so this is my code:

```
@bot.command(name="randint")
async def random_num(ctx, min_num:int, max_num:int):
    result = random.randint(min_num, max_num)
    embed=discord.Embed(color=0x1e9f9c)
    embed.add_field(name="Random number", value="min:%d, max:%d" % (min_num, max_num), inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Result", value=result, inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Now what i want to add to my code is that when a string is inputted instead of an number, it sends a error to the channel where the command was used, and also do the same thing if there was nothing inputted at all.
I searched everywhere and I also tried this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        ctx.send("bruh input numbers")
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        ctx.send("bruh you do know you have to input 2 numbers lol")
```

But when i tried this it would do nothing at all for the error, not even put the error in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you switched up the order of the arguments. Looking at the [API Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_error#discord.on_command_error) for `on_command_error`, you first need the `ctx` & *then* the `error`. Because of this, none of your `isinstance`'s will work (as `ctx` is never an instance of an error).

You're no longer getting any other errors in your terminal because you're overriding the default error handler, which by default prints them, so that no longer happens.

Also you're not `await`ing your `ctx.send`s, which will cause an error that you can't see because you're ignoring that type of error. It's recommended to `raise` all errors that you don't catch again so you can still see them.

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("bruh input numbers")
    else if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("bruh you do know you have to input 2 numbers lol")
    else:
        raise error
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to await the `ctx.send` command.
Also, I don't recommend having error handling pertain to a specific command, because down the line when errors are triggered in commands other than your `randint` command, the error message won't make sense.

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("bruh input numbers")
        raise error
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("bruh you do know you have to input 2 numbers lol")
        raise error
```

Comment: Ok, But can you please explain how to make the bot send the errors for every command not just the randint command?